# Sum of input number with do loops until

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Quick problem on my homework. I have to make a version of this code will "Do Until Loop". The first  part regarding the "please enter a positive number" works, but not the second part, that calculates the sum.

```
Sub Main()
    
    Dim sumOdd, oddinput As Integer
    Dim odd = 1

    Console.Write("Please Enter a Positive Odd Number!: ")
    oddinput = CInt(Console.ReadLine())

    Do Until oddinput < 0 Or oddinput Mod 2 = 0

        Console.Write("Please Enter a Positive Odd Number!: ")
        oddinput = CInt(Console.ReadLine())

    Loop
   
'The do until loop below is giving me the issue

    Do Until odd <= oddinput

        sumOdd += odd
        odd += 2

    Loop

    
    Console.WriteLine("The Sum of all the odd numbers up to {0} is {1}!", oddinput, sumOdd)

    Console.ReadLine() 
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: If your problem has been solved, please [accept the correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Do Until oddinput < 0 Or oddinput Mod 2 = 1
```

You were asking for an odd number, but the condition only accepted an even one.

And:

```
Do Until odd > oddinput
```

Previously, with `odd = 1` and the condition `odd <= oddinput`, for any `oddinput` bigger than `1`, the loop would have just exited.

Answer (score 0):

The first part actually does not do what you want it to.

```
oddinput < 0
```

will accept any number smaller than zero

```
oddinput Mod 2 = 0
```

will accept any even number, not odd.

But what you want is to ask the user to enter a number until it is positive and odd:

```
Do Until oddinput > 0 And oddinput Mod 2 = 1

    Console.Write("Please Enter a Positive Odd Number!: ")
    oddinput = CInt(Console.ReadLine())

Loop
```

For the second part you want it to add odd numbers until odd is bigger than oddinput, then stop.

```
Do Until odd > oddinput

    sumOdd += odd
    odd += 2

Loop
```

In your last assignment you had to use While loop so you could say: while odd is smaller or equal the final number. Here you do basically the opposite: Do until odd is bigger than the final number.
Also do not use >= as the loop would stop when odd is the same as the final number, but you want this one still to be added.

Answer (score -1):

You should initialize sumOdd at the begining.

```
sumOdd=0
```

And odd should start with 2 and not 1

```
Dim odd = 2
```

Replace also this line:

```
 Do Until odd > oddinput
```

That will work. After that you need to verify the validation because it's validating for example the -2.